# tomcat servelt sepearation folder of client and server side

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I have an a web servlet applcation under apache tomcat.
I'm using tomcat 7.0.
When I make a deploy under webapps and the name of the servlet there are the folder of the client side and the server side.
How can I seperate the 2 components, so when I make a deploy I will deploy the sever side and can put in a nother seperate place the client, gui side .

Looked in configuration at context.xml if there is a place to make the seperation of configuration.

Comment: Your badly need to upgrade to a supported version of Tomcat. Version 8.5 will reach end-of-life in March 2024, and you are still on Tomcat 7.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "server side" versus "client side". Can you edit your question and explain your situation in more detail?